# Parent NSManagedObjectContext has no changes after child is saved, but only in release mode (works in debug mode)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My setup:

- An `NSManagedObjectContext` with type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` that is connected to my `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`
- An `NSManagedObjectContext` with type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` that is a child of the private context.
- An `NSManagedObjectContext` with type `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` that is a child of the main context.

While downloading data from a server, I write data to the context of type `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`. I then save this context, which pushes changes to my main context. I then save my main context, which pushes changes to my private context. At this point, I use the `performBlock` method on the private context to save everything to my persistent store.

This works flawlessly when debugging on a device. Whenever I archive the application and run the application in release mode, my main context never receives changes even though I successfully save it's child context. I have double checked and my temporary context is indeed linked to the main context (the main context does show up as the temporary context's parent). But whenever I save the temporary context in release mode, the main context never shows any changes. I'm baffled as to why this would work in debug mode but not in release.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

groomsy

EDIT: If I archive the build using the Debug configuration, everything works as expected. Therefore there is some setting in the Release configuration that is different. I will report back with what I find.

EDIT 2: Found the culprit. So I had wrapped my save context calls in an NSAssert (in hopes of catching any failures while testing). Unfortunately, the Release configuration stripped out these assertion blocks which housed my save calls. **face palm**

Answer (score 1):

`NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is the old legacy Core Data behavior, before the notion of parent and child contexts. If you're doing an import into a child context, that child needs to be `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. I'm surprised that the combination of `performBlock:`, parent/child MOCs, and `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` works at all.

Comment: Strangely enough, changed this over to NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType as well and it still does not work. Same behavior as stated in the question.